# JTable class and multiple tables

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

is it possible to use JTable class for more than one table ? For example
I have three tables:

language (id,lang_name, published)

translators (id, name,surname, phone, email, published)

trans_lang_rel(language and translator relation. one translator can translate from one or more languages)

id, trans_id, lang_id

So, can I use JTable class for it ?

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why you want to access 3 tables from one table, when JTable was designed to access one table ?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it. Because all of the member variables of your class should match the column names in the database. So 'id' would be overwritten.

JTable is located at `/joomla/database/table.php`, you can check how it works from there.